# How can I pass Get-WMIObject Properties into a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, get-wmiobject

I'm currently trying to find a command line that is running on a client machine and if the command line running the script is found, I need to terminate that process id.  Here is what I currently have, but I'm a bit lost on what a good way to kill that ParentProcessID.

You can see in my Get-WMIObject, I'm getting the properties of CommandLine and ParentProcess ID. I can run a foreach and -match those command lines with a string.  But at this point, I don't know how to pass or link the ParentProcessID property so I can kill that ParentProcessID.

```
$process = "powershell.exe"
$GetCommand = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" |select CommandLine, ParentProcessID

foreach($command in $GetCommand){
    If($command -match "MyScript.ps1"){
    #kill ParentProcessID
    }

 }
```

Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

Comment: `if($command.CommandLine -match "MyScript.ps1"){ Stop-Process -Id $command.ParentProcessID }`

Comment: Thank you Mathias! I did not think I could pass the properties through the main varible that way.  Wow, I learned something new.

Thank you.  I'm not sure how to mark this as Answered so you get credit for it.

Comment: This is PowerShell - everything is a .NET object :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell (unlike traditional shells) - everything is a wrapped .NET object.

This means that you can reference the properties selected with `Select-Object` using the `.` operator

```
$process = "powershell.exe"
$GetCommand = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" |Select-Object CommandLine, ParentProcessID

foreach($command in $GetCommand){
    if($command.CommandLine -match "MyScript.ps1"){
        Stop-Process -Id $command.ParentProcessID
    }
 }
```